# Laravel hasOne get only one field instead of object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

There two models `user` and also `address`, which contains country, city and etc. I need to get a list of users with the city, not with the whole address. Relation is `oneToOne`. The only thing I can get, using `select['user_id', 'city']`:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John",
  "city": {
  "user_id": 3,
  "city": "Paris"
},
```

but I need:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John",
  "city": "Paris"
}
```

Of course, I can use a loop and do something like `$user->city = $user->address->city` but maybe there is a better way to solve this problem. Laravel **5.4**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor),

And append the attribute to json [appending-values-to-json](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json):

In your User model:

```php
    protected $appends = ['city'];

    public function getCityAttribute()
    {
        return $this->city->city;
    }
```

Test it like this:

```php
User::with('city')->get()->toJson();
// It will return:
// [{"id": 1, "name": "John", "city": "Paris", "city" : {"user_id": 3, "city": "Paris"}}, {...}]
```

Comment: it's not included in larave 5.4, as I know it can be used from 5.5

Comment: Regarding accessor, I'm not sure, accessors are calling during getting list + `with`

Comment: @V-K Add $appends to your model, you can get the accessor in json.

Comment: my friend, you were reading my question not accurately. I know how to get `"city" : {"user_id": 3, "city": "Paris"}}`, but I need just `"city": "Paris"`. What's why I've asked question here.

Comment: @V-K bro, the return result including just ` "city": "Paris"`, you can remove the `with()`, the `"city": "Paris"` is still in result.